# Mysql binary logs are not deleted after expiration

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, galera, mariadb-10.3, group-replication

I have 3 Mysql 5.6 nodes in one galera cluster in the first DC and 3 MariaDB 10.3 nodes in another galera cluster in the DR site. One node on the 1st DC is the master for one slave node on the DR site. In all nodes binary logs are enabled to be ready anytime act as masters. 
The problem is that despite the fact that `expire_logs_days = 2` **binary logs are not deleted in any node** . I have tried to stop one node, delete everything under `/var/lib/mysql/` and restart but nothing changed. I still delete the logs by hand using `PURGE BINARY LOG` commands. Any idea why this cloud be happening?

I have checked `expire_logs_days` with mysql command and I also have it in the `my.cnf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the binary logs was rotating normally. The problem is that `expire_logs_days=2` **means 2 days excluding the present one or something like that**, probably a translation of days in minutes. :)
The last mysql mariadb versions set binary log expiration in minutes.

Comment: `binlog_expire_logs_seconds` is in seconds in 8.0.